# What are the sap standard programs that auto delimit PB infotypes?

Tags: abap, sap-hr

What are the sap standard programs that auto delimit PB infotypes? I saw results for PA infotypes only. Thanks for the response

Comment: `I saw results` where did you see those results?

Comment: HR_MAINTAIN_MASTERDATA can do this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be a programming-related question, but there isn't enough information in it to determine where to move the question to either.